# Creating heatmaps for Google Maps with Hover functionality

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, heatmap

I am looking for a HeatMap API which provides me with the flexibility of implementing jquery hover on red points of the map.

I get latitudes and longitudes in my JSON data. I came accross [www.heatmapapi.com](http://www.heatmapapi.com), but am new to Gmap plugin. I also need to control my zoom dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) is a JavaScript library that can be used to generate web heatmaps with the html5canvas element based on your data. Heatmap instances contain a store in order to colorize the heatmap based on relative data, which means if you're adding only a single datapoint to the store it will be displayed as the hottest(red) spot, then adding another point with a higher count, it will dynamically recalculate.

You can play with different colors by changing the gradient in heatmap.js. Zoom can be controlled dynamically using ZoomIndex(GMAPV3).